# Combining Resistors

Tags: resistors

I don't know much about electrical engineering.  I'm working on a project and need a 2.2k ohm resistor, but don't have one.  However, I have 1.0k ohm and 1.2k ohm resistors.  Can I combine one of each of these in a series as seen at the top of [this page](http://www.eecs.tufts.edu/~dsculley/tutorial/voltageDividers/voltdiv2.html) in place of the 2.2k ohm resistor?  Could this cause any potential problems?  Thank you!

Comment: Yes.  Resistors in series have a total value of the sum of the individual values.

Comment: This is how a resistor decade box works, it combines resistors in series to have the sum of their resistances.  E.g. http://a.co/eF2zQaZ  and  https://hackaday.com/2013/09/18/seven-decade-programmable-resistor/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:  Combine away.

Slightly longer answer:  I would find it very difficult to imagine a scenario where it would make any difference.  If you've got the space for two parts, 2.2K is the same whether it's 1 2.2k device 22 devices of 100 ohms each.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's s worth, 2.2k is one of the standard sizes (in both the common E12 and E6 size systems).  You should have no trouble sourcing it.